# SSIS Script Task Grabbing Columns Inside an Object Variable

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, ssis

In my SSIS package, I am selecting a single row into an object variable from a database. I am then putting that variable as read-only into a script task. Is there a way to grab the individual column values from the object and put them into variables within the script task Main function to do some replacing of text? I am using VB for my scripts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cast the object variable as a DataTable.   That will then expose all the properties of a DataTable and you will be able to access columns and their values.

Comment: Nothing handy, no.  It should come up on Google easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, even you can get out complete table.
Declare object type variable say objResult.

Use Execute SQL Task(ESQLT) to fetch data from the database. Set result type property to 'Full Result Set' of the ESQLT. You might also use 'single result set', for now just skip it.

Then go to result tab of the ESQLT and replacenewresultname with 0 and use the object type variable objResult.

Now connect ESQLT task to foreach loop task.

In the foreach loop task, go to the collection tab and set foreach loop enumerator to ado enumerator from the drop down list.

Below there you will find a drop down list, select objResult.

Go to the next tab, and set/create variables according to the column name order of your select query. 
Start from 0 to n.

Then drag a script task inside the foreach loop container.

Set your read only and write only variables and do what you want to. All columns values will enter into the script task one by one row wise.

Note: you might need to take care of variables data type and handle dbnull values according to your database.